# I want to make TextViews of RecyclerView Clickable and change the Background of Selected TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, textview

I have some TextView in my Recycler View and I want to make them Clickable and Change the Background of Selected TextView, but don't know how to do it, It would be very Helpful if anyone could Help Me.

Comment: Use Material Text Button or Material Toogle Button.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be on your adapter so it affects each item individually

var textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))

You could use a flag so it changes the colour back and forth whenever you click it